# Spanning multiple relations with conditional expresessions in Django 2.0

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

Consider the following models (in pseudo code) in Django 2.0:

```
class m_Discussion(models.Model):
    ...

class m_Comment(models.Model):
    fk_discussion = models.ForeignKey('m_Discussion', related_name='comments')

class m_Tag(models.Model):
    fk_comment = models.ForeignKey('m_Comment', related_name='tags')
```

I would like to get the all Discussions which have at least 50% (arbitrary) comments which are tagged (i.e. have at least one tag)

My current solution looks like this:

```
m_Discussion.objects.annotate(
    ratio_tagged_comments=Cast(
        Sum(
            Case(
                When(
                    comments__tags__isnull=False,
                    then=1.0
                ),
                default=0.0,
                output_field=FloatField()
            )
        ) / F('count_comments'),  
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
).filter(
    ratio_tagged_comments__gte=0.5,
)
```

I'm worried about the line `comments__tags__isnull=False`.

Is this how it works?

I found nothing about using conditional expressions while spanning multiple relations.

The SQL looks approximately like this:

```
SELECT 
    "corpus_m_discussion"."id_discussion", 
    "corpus_m_discussion"."title" 
FROM 
    "corpus_m_discussion" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "corpus_m_comment" ON (
        "corpus_m_discussion"."id" = "corpus_m_comment"."fk_discussion_id"
    ) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "corpus_m_tag" ON (
        "corpus_m_comment"."id" = "corpus_m_tag"."fk_comment_id"
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    "corpus_m_discussion"."id" 
HAVING 
    (
        COUNT("corpus_m_comment"."id") >= 5 
        AND (
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN ("corpus_m_tag"."id" IS NOT NULL) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END
            ) / (
                COUNT("corpus_m_comment"."id") -1
            )
        ):: double precision >= 0.7
    )
```

Which row in the 'corpus_m_tag' table is compared here: `CASE WHEN ("corpus_m_tag"."id" IS NOT NULL) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END`.
To me this seems odd but I'm not that experienced with 'having', 'count', 'case', ... clauses in SQL.

Any input is appreciated

**Update**
My main problem is to understand the annotation spanning **multiple** relations. I would understand a query with a simple annotation spanning only one relation as examples of these can be found all over the internet and the docs.

Comment: `CASE` is an immediate/inline IF statement.  `HAVING` is just like `WHERE` but applied ***after*** a `GROUP BY`.  `COUNT(id)` simply counts the number of rows where `id` isn't NULL *(aggregate functions essentially skip NULLs)*.

Comment: @MatBailie Ok so the something like `("corpus_m_tag"."id" IS NOT NULL)` happens in the context of the comments of the current discussions? Because of course it's useless if its simply checks all the rows from a table.

Comment: `CASE` is applied one row at a time.  That's why there is a `SUM()` wrapped around it.  The `CASE` statement is just an `IIF`, and as written returns `1` when a row's id `IS NOT NULL`, otherwise it returns a `0`.  The `SUM()` adds those 1's and 0's up within each `GROUP`.  *(In your case it gives the same result as `COUNT("corpus_m_tag"."id")`)*

Comment: @MatBailie but to me it sounds as if the `SUM` would "iterate" over all the rows in 'corpus_m_tag' and not only over the rows of 'corpus_m_tag' which have a foreignkey-relationship with a specific comment

Comment: ...that have actually been joined by the LEFT JOIN.  Sorry, to much to explain in comments, I think you should try a SQL tutorial covering LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and Conditional Aggregation.

Comment: @MatBailie I agree I really have to have a look at some tutorials :) 
But regarding my specific example, does it work as it is?
Thank you!

Comment: At present I can't tell.  You haven't given any example data, there is little indication of how the tables relate *(I **assume** that one discussion can have 0..many comments and each comment can have 0..many tags?)* This also means that you haven't clearly articulated what you want the query to do.  So, what I ***can*** tell you is what the SQL currently does.  ..

Comment: LEFT join all discussions to all their comments and all those comments' tags. Group those records to ensure only one per discussion. Count the number of comments present. Exclude discussions with fewer than 5 comments.  Count the number of tags, count the number of comments *(then subtract 1 for some reason)*.  Exclude discussions where the ratio of those two values is under 70%.

Comment: This will have problems when there are exactly one comment.  You'll find 1 comment, subtract 1 from the value, resulting in zero.  Then use it to get a divide by zero error.  Instead you could use `#tags >= (#comments - 1) * 0.7` though I'm still perplexed about why you have the `- 1` in there.

Comment: This may also have unintended consequences if one comment has more than one tag.  Say a discussion has 10 comments, 9 or which have no tags and one of which has 7 tags, that's still a 70% ratio.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Like I say, I could write forever.  Unfortunately I don't have time and it's not really what SO is for.  Two recommendations are:  Give a concrete example with example data that describes all the relevant corner cases you would test in unit-testing.  Enough to describe how the data behaves in all conditions, without ambiguity.  Include the exact results that you want and why they should happen *(and why other results should not happen).  Secondly, sorry, those tutorials are going to be really important for you.

Comment: @MatBailie 'division by zero' can not happen because first I filter for discussion with min 5 comments. This '-1' is really confusing but something I need, I thought I removed it for this example. What you describe what the query does is not what I want. I will investigate this further and maybe come back to ask again with a more clear example. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're describing `short circuiting`, where later sub-expressions cease being evaluated when an earlier sub-expression guarantees the result of the whole compound expression.  In SQL this is not guaranteed in all databases for the example you gave.  To guarantee it you need a nested query *(giving different levels of scope)* : `SELECT * FROM (SELECT a, b FROM x WHERE b > 0) AS nested_expression WHERE a / b >= 0.7`